# iPhone/iPad : Check for invalid characters in a textbox made for Integers only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, ipad

I noticed that the iPhone OS is pretty good about picking out Integer values when asked to.  Specifically, if you use

```
NSString *stringName = @"6(";
int number = [stringName intValue];
```

the iPhone OS will pick out the 6 and turn the variable number into 6.  However, in more complex mistypes, this also makes the int variable 6:

```
NSString *stringName = @"6(5";
int number = [stringName intValue];
```

The iPhone OS misses the other digit, when what could have possibly been the user trying to enter the number 65, the OS only gets the number 6 out of it.  I need a solution to check a string for invalid characters and return NO if there is anything other than an unsigned integer in a textbox.  This is for iPad, and currently there is no numeric keyboard like the iPhone has, and I'm instead limited to the standard 123 keyboard.

I was thinking that I need to use NSRange and somehow loop through the entire string in the textbox, and checking to see if the current character in the iteration is a number.  I'm lost as far as that goes.  I can think of testing it against zero, but zero is a valid integer.

Can anyone help?

Comment: zero is a valid integer, but it's also prohibited by recent revisions of Apple's developer agreement. As are text boxes.
:P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` method NSResponder mentioned, and check the replacement string with the `NSString` method `-rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`, like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)newString
{
    // create a character set containing everything except the decimal digits
    // (you might want to cache this, as inverting the set probably isn't fast)
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumericCharacters = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    // and check whether there's a character in the string that's not in that set
    if([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumericCharacters].location != NSNotFound)
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Or, better yet, tell a number formatter to attempt to parse the string. That will handle negative numbers, decimal points, and locale changes (e.g., different decimal points).

Comment: This may lead to a problem when user presses backspace.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use an [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

With the NSScanner, you could do `-scanInt:`, then check `-isAtEnd`

Answer (score 0):

I'd just have the `UITextField`'s delegate veto any attempt to insert non-numeric characters.  See `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {

            if([string isEqualToString:@"\b"] || [string isEqualToString:@"0"] ||  [string isEqualToString:@"1"] ||[string isEqualToString:@"2"] || [string isEqualToString:@"3"] || [string isEqualToString:@"4"] || [string isEqualToString:@"5"] || [string isEqualToString:@"6"] || [string isEqualToString:@"7"] || [string isEqualToString:@"8"] || [string isEqualToString:@"9"] || [string isEqualToString:@"."])
            {
                return YES;
            }
           else{
                return NO;
           }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to check for the backspace character—it isn't entered as such, you just get an empty string which replaces whatever character is just before the caret.